# PhP Regex or Basename()

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract filenames from a list of files with pathes like :

```
/a/b/c/d/file1.jpg
/e/f/g/h/file2.png
/i/j/k/l/file3.txt
```

I want to get a string that is a valid filename (for linux) that is between a "/" is a jpeg file (ends with ".jpg").
In this example, "file1" would be the only valid match.

At the moment I have this RegEx :

```
/(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\.(js))/gim
```

I don't really know if it's better to do this with RegEx or if it's better / possible with basename().

The goal I want to achieve is to get all the strings that match to be placed in an array.
Don't know if I'm doing this right though.

Comment: Well, you can forget about basename.

Comment: regex > basename (my opinion)

Comment: Hum, ok. Regex it is I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex isn't required here. I've assumed you can get your paths into an array.

```
<?php
    $text = file_get_contents("list.txt");

    $foo = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);

    $bar = array(); 

        foreach($foo as $key => $value){
            if(pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "jpg"){
                $bar[] = basename($foo[$key],".".pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            }
        }

    print_r($bar);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => file1 )
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ewkUHs

Comment: Well first thanks for your quick answer ! I actually don't know if this would work because the block I want to parse is a .txt file and I don't have only the path as content in each line.

Comment: Well in that case you'll have to build your array first. How are you getting the data into the script? If you've got it in a string you can do this: $lines = explode(PHP_EOL,$content);

$lines becomes an array, explode splits the string by EOL (end of line), the $content parameter is your input string.

Comment: I didn't code the file I/O yet, but I thought of importing the data thanks fopen().

Comment: Something like : $text = file_get_contents("list.txt");. But the RegEx part is the one I'm really stuck on.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Personally, I recommend avoiding RegEx where possible ;)

Comment: Thank you very much ! Yeah, I tend to do avoid RegEx too because I don't always visualize the different scenarios that could cause unintended matches.